# form field is blank when input value retreived from database is 0

Tags: php, html

I have the following html-php input field on a form page:

```
<input type="text" id="subnet" name="subnet" class="inputText70px" maxlength="3" value=
      <?php
        if (!empty($eqptCheck['subnet'])){
          echo '"'.$ipAddressArr['subnet'].'">.';
        }else{
          echo '"">.';
        }
      ?>
```

Whenever I have any value other than 0 for the subnet it is displays properly in the page's input field. But when the subnet value is 0 the page's field is just empty. I assume my php must be the problem. Can anyone see what the issue with my php is that causes the issue?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php . Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `empty` is true if for `value == 0`. So when your subnet value is 0, then the `!empty` condition is false and moves along to `else` that renders an empty `""` value for the intput field.

If you instead use `!is_null` in place of `!empty` I think that should resolve your issue.

```
<input type="text" id="subnet" name="subnet" class="inputText70px" maxlength="3" value=
  <?php
    if (!is_null($eqptCheck['subnet'])){
      echo '"'.$ipAddressArr['subnet'].'">.';
    }else{
      echo '"">.';
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: would there be any advantage to checking for both conditions like so: `if (!is_null($eqptCheck['subnet']) || !empty($eqptCheck['subnet']){`, since either one in OR `||` should be picked up independently of the other?